# Where is the fork functionality in GitLab CE 6.8.2?

Tags: gitlab

I hope this is not an incredibly stupid question.

According to what I can find online, it seems forking was added to GitLab in version 5.2. However, I can't seem to find in trace of it in the web UI. Or the help files. Or much anywhere else.

Is this perhaps a premium feature or something?
Or should it be activated/enabled somehow?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to substantiate some of the above: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gitlabhq/sk5HmK8dxCM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I was being an idiot (sort of).
Seems if you login with a DIFFERENT user (i.e. a user who is NOT the owner of the project), the fork functionality shows up clear and plain.

Excellent then.

Props to the GitLab team - loving it!

Answer (score 5):

Also a side-note, if you haven't committed any files yet, fork option will not show to other users. you need to at least add a readme file in order fork a project.

The scenario : you have a main project at startup phase and multiple developers will be working on it. You created main project in root repo, logged out , logged with your user to for project for initial set up, fork option is not there.